# How can I periodically backup a Postgres database in a Docker container, when volume mounts aren't working?

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, windows-8.1, docker-toolbox

I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit, and the latest version of both Virtualbox and Docker-Toolbox. Most everything works properly, however as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117938/unable-to-start-any-container-when-volumes-are-enabled-docker-toolbox), mounting the data directory of a Postgresql container throws up errors. This is kind of annoying, since I'd like to be able to have a backup of the database to commit / have on hand.

Is there some other method to do this? I was thinking about using Docker signals and catching sigkill/sigterm, but I was hoping there was a better built in method - either in Docker, or Postgresql itself, rather than just running a script to export .sql on container stop.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: The most likely solution is a programming solution - a bash script to catch a signal and execute a database backup. I had considered Super User at first, but I figured given the information I had read up to this point and the related questions I've seen here - SO was ideal.

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

It looks like I'm in the right place according to your link. This a problem unique to software development.

Comment: What software tool are you referring to? You are trying to backup a SQL database in a lightweight VM. Take it to a site that exists for the questions. Maybe you should edit the question, and bring it back on-topic. Providing  your code is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Programmers have started to program replacements of sysadmin people. My company replaced 10 of them with only 1 skilled programmer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why you do not use pg_dump or pg_basebackup or solution like pgbarman? After 4 years of experiences with PostgreSQL I cannot recommend any "non-PostgreSQL" solution.